# How do I clone structs in Rust without using either Copy or Clone?

Tags: rust

How do I create deep copies of each of these three styles of structs?

```
// A unit struct
struct Thing;

// A tuple struct
struct Thingy(u8, i32);

// regular
struct Location {
    name: String,
    code: i32,
}
```

Can I do this without using either the `Copy` or `Clone` traits? If a struct is already defined and doesn't have these trait implemented, is there a work-around?

```
// without this:
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Location {
    name: String,
    code: i32,
}
```

Comment: [See this entry in RBE book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/clone.html)

Comment: _"Can I do this without using either Copy, and Clone traits?"_ It doesn't sound reasonable not to use these traits to make copies. Can you provide additional context around your concern? What is your current attempt at creating these copies?

Comment: You can't copy a `string`, use clone

Comment: Is it guaranteed that all the fields are public and  implement Clone or Copy and there’s a public constructor?

Comment: @Shepmaster I think all fields are public and implement Copy and there's a public constructor.

Comment: It seems like the question is, why aren't they already `Clone`? Can you just file a bug with the existing library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit struct contains no data, so a "deep copy" would be just another instance of it: `let thing_clone = Thing;`

For the other types, you'd just manually clone the fields and create a new object out of the cloned fields. Assuming there is a `new` method for both `Thingy` and `Location`:

```
let thingy_clone = Thingy::new(thingy.0, thingy.1);

let location_clone = Location::new(location.name.clone(), location.code);
```

Note that I only explicitly wrote `.clone()` for the String field. That is because u8 and i32 implement `Copy` and will therefore be automatically copied, when needed. No explicit copying/cloning required.

That said, it's definitely more idiomatic to use the `Clone` trait. If `Thing`, `Thingy` and `Location` are part of an external library, you could file a bug report, asking for `Clone` to be implemented for those structs.